# SAPui5 Routing Passing Parameters

Tags: routes, sapui5

I'm trying to passing parameter through routing as step 32 in this link,(https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/guide/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef.html) but it's not working, I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

ListController

```
        onPressItemDetail: function(evt) {

        var oSource = evt.getSource();
        var oBind = oSource.getBindingContext();
        var sPath = oBind.getPath();

        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("changeitem", { path : sPath});

    },
```

Manifest.json

```
        "routes": [{
            "pattern": "",
            "name": "first",
            "target": "first"
        }, {
            "pattern": "secondview",
            "name": "second",
            "target": "second"
        }, {
            "pattern": "checkout",
            "name": "checkout",
            "target": "checkout"
        }, {
            "name": "changeitem/{path}",
            "pattern": "changeitem",
            "target": "changeitem"
        }],
```

changeitemcontroller

```
    onInit: function() {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        var rChangeItem = oRouter.getRoute("changeitem");
        rChangeItem.attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
    },

    _onObjectMatched: function (evt) {

        this.getView().bindElement({
            path: "/" + evt.getParameter("arguments").path,
            model: "item"
        });

    },
```

The error showed is :  Can not navigate to route with name changeitem because the route does not exist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned `pattern` to `name` property of route.

It should be:

```
{
    "name": "changeitem",
    "pattern": "changeitem/{path}",
    "target": "changeitem"
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. it was truly wrong..after fix this.. it's showing me the follow error:  ** Uncaught Error: Invalid value "/despesas/0" for segment "{path}" **

Comment: Possible value for the specified path could be "changeitem/0" or "changeitem/anyString"

Comment: If you directly use sPath in {path} parameter it will be end up adding // double slashes. You can try to remove the the first / and see if it works. But in best practices you should not have any / in the parameters of the pattern , it should be alphanumeric string, it can be numbers or string.